# How are clean URLs with 200 response codes being managed without doing a RewriteMap?

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to know how Drupal handles clean URLs without getting a redirection 302 response.

When you have clean URLs enabled, the `?q=123` part of the link goes to `/my-node-title` and you don't get a 302 redirect but a clean 200 response.

My question is about the code that enables this, and not about how to sort things from the UI.

I want to understand how it does work, because it should do a `RewriteMap` from apache, but in Drupal installations people don't usually get access to modifying Apache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Apache mod rewrite module is used. `/some/path` is rewritten internally by Apache to `index.php?q=some/path` [Credit: mpdonadio].

`index.php` bootstraps Drupal. Drupal  determines if it is able to generate a response for the path passed in the URL query `q` parameter - in this case `/some/path`. If the user has permission to access the path, the response is returned with a 200 HTTP status.

If Drupal is not able to generate a response for the path, it returns a 404 status. If it can generate a response, but the user has no permission, a 403 status is returned. Redirects send the appropriate status.

Custom modules are also able to specify status codes when returning responses.

Comment: I think it would be more clear to say that `/some/path` is rewritten *internally* by apache to `index.php?q=some/path`, which then handles the response.  A 301 or 302 would be an *external* rewrite.

Comment: Yeah - that! Haha. I’ll edit my response. Thanks.

Comment: I cleaned up my whole response.